# can't source script in a current directory

Tags: linux, bash, sh

So apparently, I can't `source` a script if that script is in the current directory. For example,

```
# source some/dir/script.sh
Ok
```

works fine, but if I'm in the same dir as the script, it errors out:

```
# cd some/dir
# source script.sh
-sh: source: script.sh: file not found
```

What gives? Is the only way around this to change directory?

I'm using bash v4.2.10 on Angstrom Linux if that's relevant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting the source man page:

> source filename [arguments]
>
> ....
>
> If filename does not contain a slash, file
> names  in  PATH  are used to find the directory containing file-
> name.

So... `source` is trying to search your `script.sh` in the folders contained in `PATH`.

If you want to source a file in the current folder use

```
source ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path -- `source /root/path/to/some/dir/script.sh` -- should sort you.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the file is in the wrong format. I FTP'd a Korn Shell script from Windows. I could edit it, but got "not found [No such file or directory]" when I tried to run it. It turned out it was in DOS format, which was indicated in the file name line when I edited it in vi. After I re-FTP'd it, making sure it was being transferred as ASCII, it ran fine.