# ksh source file: cannot open [No such file or directory]

Tags: ksh

Could not fix my error with the current solutions given in SO. Hence this post.
Im using ksh version as below in a linux system( `Linux version 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b9.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012` ).

```
[userid@host home]$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

I have  2 files in the same directory. Both given `chmod 777` permissions

```
testvar.env
testrun.ksh
```

Contents of `testrun.ksh`

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
. testvar.env
echo $month
```

Contents of testvar.env

```
export month=jan
export user=abc
```

But when i do `ksh testrun.ksh` i get this error

```
testrun.ksh[2]: .: testvar.env: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Tried adding below line on top of `testvar.env`. But no luck

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
```

Possibilities:

- Is this to do with the ksh version?
- Ffile permissions?
- Location it looks is somewhere else?
- Does it only source other ksh files?
- .env extension has anything to do?

I have also tried with replacing the file with another file from the same dir. Same result. So it seems not an issue with `settings` file

### Update

I used @shellter s comment below to use `. $PWD/settings.env` to fix the error, Even though I didn't get the reason for the error. I think I found the answer here [can't source script in a current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889921/cant-source-script-in-a-current-directory).

Comment: Believe the error messages! ;-) .... you're not starting your `startrun` in the same dir as the `setting.env` file. Best to do `. /full/path/to/settings.env`. Don't include `#!/bin/*/ksh` in a file that is to be sourced. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter . Thanks . But both files are present in the same dir. Also i did not want to use the full path because the whole dir can be moved to another location. Say production.

Comment: To debug, add a line just before your `. settings.env`. : `echo PWD=$PWD ; ls -l setting.env` . Good luck.

Comment: Do you have `cd /some/other/dir` in `startrun` ?

Comment: @shellter: thanks again. i tried debugging again and got the same path where both files reside.

Comment: @WalterA: no no `cd` is used.

Comment: The error `startrun[35]` mentions line 35. Can you `cp startrun testrun` and try to look for the smallest file where the error occurs. And add this version of your file in your question. I think that a testrun file with only the next two lines will work: `. settings.env` and `echo "month=${month}"`

Comment: *"and try to look for the smallest file ..."* : i.e. try to edit `testrun` down to 3-5 lines that still demonstrate this error. Then edit your Q to include that code. Is it possible that your `settings.env` is really `settings.env<whitespace>`? You can check this with `for f in sett* ; do echo "f=${f}Z" ; done`. If you see don't see `settings.envZ`, then that is your problem (very unlikely, but it does happen ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: And, if  your script/files have been anywhere near MS-Windows, then eliminate the problem of `\r\n` line endings by running `dos2unix myScript.sh` to convert to *nix friendly `\n` line endings. Good luck.

Comment: Please see the modification done to the post. Created sample test code to reproduce the error. The code is is unix format. no \r.  So i see it works in 2 ways. One is usng `. $PWD/testvar.env`  or by using `. ./testvar.env` . yes if i use `. ./testvar.env` it identifies the file